# Can't write to usb device using node-usb until manually doing so using echo

Tags: node.js, typescript, ubuntu, npm, usb

this is a very specific situation but I'm hoping someone can help me.

I have two cash drawers hooked up to a machine running ubuntu, each through a usb controller. On that machine is a node project from which I want to be able to send a signal to each drawer so as to open it.

I'm using the npm usb package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/usb

--- EDIT ---

After running the project directly on the host machine and not in a docker container I have the same issue, so this is not a docker problem

--- EDIT ---

I use the following code with the node project (I'm using typescript), to find the two devices. It finds them just fine. The problem comes later when I want to write to the usb controllers.

```
lookForDrawers() {
    // get the devices using their product id
    this.devices = usb.getDeviceList().filter((device: usb.Device) => {
        return device.deviceDescriptor.idProduct === 8963;
    });

    for (const device of this.devices) {
        this.openDrawer(device);
    }
}
```

The openDrawer() function looks like this:

```
openDrawer(d: usb.Device) {
    d.open();
    const iFace: usb.Interface = d.interface(0);
    // detach kernal driver if necessary
    if (iFace.isKernelDriverActive()) {
        iFace.detachKernelDriver();
    }
    iFace.claim();
    // I could write a loop to specifically find the OutEndpoint for this device, but I know it is at position 1
    const outEndPoint: usb.OutEndpoint = iFace.endpoints[1] as usb.OutEndpoint;
    outEndPoint.transfer(new Buffer(1), (err) => {
        console.log('transfer finished');
        if (err) {
            console.warn('TRANSFER ERROR', err);
        }
        iFace.release((err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.warn('RELEASE ERROR', err);
            }
            console.log('reattaching');
            iFace.attachKernelDriver();
            d.close();
        });   
    });
}
```

Now this code runs all the way through with no errors whatsoever. Unfortunately the drawers don't open.

So now's where things get confusing for me.

Obviously my first thought was to make sure that sending a signal to those usb devices would actually translate to a drawer opening.

By running

```
ls -l /sys/bus/usb-serial/devices
```

I could confirm that the controllers could be accessed through /dev/ttyUSB0 and /dev/ttyUSB1

Then when I ran the following (obviously not what I'll be wanting to do in the final version):

```
sudo chmod o+rw /dev/ttyUSB0
sudo echo '1' > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

The drawer at that location did indeed open. But what's weird is that now my typescript code above also worked! As in, every time I ran "openDrawer" on that device, the drawer opened! Running the above on ttyUSB1 would allow my node project to also open the second drawer.

If I restart the computer, the drawers no longer open from the node project, unless I run the echo command.

It's not because of the chmod. I tried just running that, and the node approach still didn't open the drawer. But sending the echo would somehow 'unlock' that drawer for my node project.

So my question is, does anyone have an inkling what might be going on?

Comment: Could you clarify where you executed the commands? I guess you executed everything in your docker container.
If so, does it work when you execute it directly on the host (without docker)?

Comment: Hey @TmTron of course I should have tried that first. I ran the node project on the host machine without docker, but the behaviour persists. So this is not a docker issue, it's an issue with the node project. Maybe somewhere in where I'm using the usb package I'm doing something wrong. However, it is strange that it does work after using the echo technique.

Comment: your shell and node code are doing completely different and unrelated things. why won't you explain where it came from? does your drawer have a model number? does it come with any documentation?

Comment: The drawer just responds to a signal, any signal. That's why echoing '1' is enough. Usually that signal is sent through the printer, but we're trying this usb approach using a converter (just search usb cash drawer trigger to see what I'm talking about). Though you say the two kinds of code do unrelated things, they do in fact perform the exact same function, but the node code only works after having performed the shell code once. As for where it came from, I wrote it, following the guides on the npm usb page.